# Two separate tables on Hadoop from from two files in HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to build two Hadoop tables from one HDFS directory.

So I'd like table `file1` from file `1.tsv` and another table `file2` from file `2.tsv`. But both are inside one HDFS directory `/tmp/ip`.

```
# create hdfs directory
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/ip

# put my two tsv files
hadoop fs -put /tmp/data/1.tsv tmp/ip/
hadoop fs -put /tmp/data/2.tsv tmp/ip/
```

Now in Hive's CLI

```
--in Hive CLI to build table
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file1
(id STRING,Code STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE

-- failed solution because there's two files
LOCATION 'tmp/ip';

-- failed solution but don't understand why
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tmp/ip/1.tsv' INTO TABLE file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding failed solution:

> -- failed solution but don't understand why `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tmp/ip/1.tsv' INTO TABLE file1` failed.

This is failing due to keyword `LOCAL`. Hive is looking for file on local file system. You can try by not using this.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'tmp/ip/1.tsv' INTO table file1`
```